# Throughput Shaping timer- Externalising

Tags: jmeter, load, throughput, workload

I want to externalise the value for throughput shaping timer But not from Jmeter or User.properties as I have couple of other script to be executed with different work load model. I want a separate property file specifying the load pattern can you kindly suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`load_profile` property](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing), you can define the desired Throughput Shaping Timer load model via it.

If you don't want to write down the value into *jmeter.properties* or *user.properties* file to permanently change the profile you can pass it via -J command line argument instead like:

```
jmeter -Jload_profile=const(10,10s) line(10,100,1m) step(5,25,5,1h) -n -t ...
```

Having separate file is also not a problem,

1. Create, i.e. `test1.properties` file in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Put your desired load profile there:

   ```
   load_profile=const(10,10s) line(10,100,1m) step(5,25,5,1h)
   ```
3. Pass this file to JMeter via `-q` command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -q test1.properties -n -t ...
   ```
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for 2nd test, you will be able to run it like:

   ```
   jmeter -q test2.properties -n -t ...
   ```

References:

- [Full list of JMeter's command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)